# How to convert XElement to XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

How can I convert XElement into XDocument? Is there some built-in method for this?
The only way I can think of is without `new XDocument(xelement.ToString())` which will result in creating big strings and then parsing them, thus reducing the performance.

Comment: i actually tried it, "Task.Run(parser.GetEvent(new XDocument(outXe)));" but saw an error , thought it was because of the conversion, turned out i was missing the ()=>

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Just pass the `XElement` to the constructor of `XDocument`:

```
var xdoc = new XDocument(new XElement("a", "b"));
```

Comment: If it is a new `XElement`, you could also grab the `Document` property.

Comment: Is `XElement.Document` always non-null?

Answer (score 4):

I've had great success with this:

`var xDoc = XDocument.Load(xml.CreateReader());`